# How to reference a list in a field object in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I've got a datasource object that contains a `Collection` of other objects. 
For example I'm returning a `Manager` object that contains a `List` of `Employees`.

I'm returning back `JRDataSource` object of type `Manager` to the actual jasper report. I'm unclear on how I can loop through the employees in the jasper report itself using the *`$F`* field tags.

Answer (score 1):

I use a subreport to show the objects of the Collection 
use `new  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{the collectin})` as the subreport's data sourse expression